# Sampling from marginal densities using the joint

Tags: sampling, conditional-probability, marginal-distribution

I have seen this approach [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/213052/sampling-from-marginal-distribution-using-conditional-distribution) in different places. Hence, I suppose that the following  method is correct.

Let $f_{X,Y,Z}(x,y,z)=f_{X|Y,Z}(x|y,z)f_Y(y)f_Z(z)$ and I can easily sample from these 3 densities.

To sample from the marginal $f_X(x)$ we can do:

1. For $j=1,\cdots,N$
2. Sample $(y,z)^j=y^j \sim f_Y, z^j \sim f_Z$
3. Sample $(x,y,z)^j = x^j \sim f_{X|Y,Z}(\cdot|y^j,z^j)$
4. Keep only $\{x\}$

Is it correct?

My question is, can this method be used to sample from $f_{X|Y}(x|y)$ for example?

Comment: That is correct!

Comment: what about f(x|y)? because i guess  keeping {x,y} is equivalent to f(x,y). Right?

Comment: By definition, the marginal density is what you obtain when you ignore the other variables.  Thus, if your algorithm *just happens* to generate one or more of those other variables, you are under no obligation to pay attention to them.